# Tree/Find command on symlinks

Tags: gnome-terminal, tree

I have a folder with symlinks which are pointing to other folders, how can i recursively look into those folders? I would like to do a grep on those results to search for matches.

doing **tree** will only list the symlink as files.

Comment: `grep -r 'somestring' *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` with the `-L` option, e.g.,

```
find -L . -type f -exec grep foo {} \;
```

That makes `find` follow symbolic links.  Quoting [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> **`-L`**
>       Cause the file information and file type evaluated for each symbolic link encountered as a path operand on the command line or encountered during the traversal of a file hierarchy to be those of the file referenced by the link, and not the link itself. If the referenced file does not exist, the file information and type shall be for the link itself.